# remove .php extension in between of a url

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

http://localhost/mydomain/category.php/5a05ee1037631242/we-will-rock-yaa

How can I remove .php extension from betwee the url. I am using core php for my projet. Can Anyone help.

Thank You!

Comment: What webserver are you running? If it is Nginx, you can just simply change the extension of the files it passes to the php socket.

Comment: Please provide more info what are you doing.

Comment: https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

Answer (score 0):

if you are using IIS then you need to install URL Rewrite which u can find using the wpilauncher and in your webconfig you put this in the `<system.webServer>` tag.

```
`<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="hide .php extension" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php" matchType="IsFile" />
    </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.php" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>`
```

you can use it with other extensions like html and asp aswell.

If you are using xampp then you need to use .htaccess and write your rewrite code(some google can help u find it. i use IIS myself and don't have the config).

I do not know which one you are using so i wrote an answer based on IIS which is what i am using.